# How to use array from python to javascript? Django

Tags: python, django, parsing, django-templates, templatetags

Before you say its duplicate !!
I know how to parse by using dump() in views, but right now I want to receive an array of dictionaries from a custom template tag to JavaScript.

This is in my custom_template.py

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context = True)
def messageRequest(context):
    request = context['request']
    messageData = Message.objects.all()
    jsMessageData = []
    if 'user' in request.COOKIES:
        currentUser = request.COOKIES.get('user')
    i = 0
    for i in range(messageData):
        if messageData[i].receiver == currentUser:
            jsMessageData.append(messageData[i])
        if messageData[i].sender == currentUser:
            jsMessageData.append(messageData[i])
        i += 1

    print(jsMessageData)
    return dumps(jsMessageData)
```

For my template index.html I want to use it in JavaScript to display the messages-
I tried this

```
messageData = Json.parse("{% messageRequest %}"); 
// i want to store it as array
// throws error "'QuerySet' object cannot be interpreted as an integer" when looping through it
```

also,

```
messageData = Json.parse("{% messageRequest|escapejs %}");
// i read this somewhere and it works fine when array is passed through render request but here it gives error as it considers escapejs as part of block tag.
```

Any help is appreciated, I am sort of beginner so please try to give comprehensive explanation an example will be really helpful.

Edit: This is my model-

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    receiver = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return (self.sender + '-' + self.receiver)
```

I have progressed in a few things you can check the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67656267/how-to-convert-a-array-of-dictionaries-in-form-of-string-into-an-array-javascrip?noredirect=1#comment119585311_67656267)

Comment: Is there a reason for checking sender and receiver for current user and appending it to the same list. My Question is do you want the sender and receiver data in the same list, and can you share your `Message Model` as well

Comment: Actually its important to keep sender's name as it is associated with the message. You can consider it as a chatapp where i need the sender's name. and it didn't actually matter if i removed receiver from array cause they are passed in as dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
@register.simple_tag(takes_context = True)
def messageRequest(context):
    request = context['request']
    if 'user' in request.COOKIES:
        currentUser = request.COOKIES.get('user')
    messageData = [Message.objects.filter(sender=currentUser).values()]
    return messageData
```

Also you can use `@login_required` decorator to allow only logged in users to access the view, and then you can access the `current_user = request.user`

In you template you should add

```
message_data = {{ message_data | safe }}
```

You have to pass `message_data` in the context of your view os that it can be accessed in the template.

You can perform operations like filter etc. using vanilla javascript or using Jquery.

Comment: Thanks but the point is how can I call this in javascript cause its giving me errors.
also for the filter I need to check both- when current user is either sender or receiver.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Upu need to add `message_data = {{ message_data | safe }}` in you template to access `message_data`

Comment: I think you are taking it wrong, I don't have choice to pass it through views, that's the reason I created a tag. And for using a tag syntax goes like {% functionname %}
I cannot use | safe with it or it will throw error of undefined.